# How can I attach some jQuery to a function that already exists?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following mark-up:

```
    <dt>

        <input id="p_method_checkmo" value="checkmo" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Check / Money order" onclick="payment.switchMethod('checkmo')" class="radio" />
        <label for="p_method_checkmo">Check / Money order </label>
</dt>
    <dt>
        <input id="p_method_ccsave" value="ccsave" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Credit Card (saved)" onclick="payment.switchMethod('ccsave')" class="radio" />
        <label for="p_method_ccsave">Credit Card (saved) </label>
</dt>
```

I need to snag some jQuery onto the click (or change) events.  After lots of debugging, I've found that the inline onclick event is over-ruling and jQuery selectors that I try to use.  Is there any way I can plug some jQuery to run whenever that method (payment.switchMethod) is run?  I thought about using preventDefault() to stop the click event on document ready, but I'm not sure if this is a good idea, or the best way of going about things.

I **CANNOT** edit the mark up in any way, unfortunately.

Any advice is massively appreciated.  I've attached the jQuery below for reference:

```
    // Check for payment selection.  Upon selection mark it as 'hitpayment' in db
jQuery("input[name=payment\\[method\\]]:radio").change(function(){
    alert('hello');
    var cartPalPayment = {};

    cartPalPayment['user_id'] = '<?=$_SESSION['user_id']?>';
    cartPalPayment['referer'] = '<?=$_SESSION['referer']?>';
    cartPalPayment['license_key'] = cartPalLicenseKey;

    jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'integration/magento1.4/set_payment.php',
        cache: false,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: cartPalPayment
        });
});
```

Comment: mike, i presume it's not possible to remove onclick="payment.switchMethod('ccsave')" ?? and then move that processing into your jquery methods (where required)

Comment: He said it's not possible to edit the markup in anyway, he bolded it too

Comment: try `.removeAttr('onclick');`

Comment: amr - oops, just noticed that!! - monday morning 'blues' i guess :). but yes, along the lines of reigel's '.removeAttr('onclick');'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so it sounds like you need to run the original function as well. Just swap out (redefine) the `payment.switchMethod` function with your own, and call it from within your new function:

```
var evilFunction = payment.switchMethod;
// Ninja-swap payment.switchMethod() with your own.
payment.switchMethod = function(evilArgs) {
   // Do whatever you want here
   alert("Got your nose");

   // Call original function
   evilFunction(evilArgs);
};
```

Just be sure to run the above on document load (or anytime AFTER `payment.switchMethod` was defined). You're effectively injecting your own code into `payment.switchMethod` so you don't even need to attach event listeners to the element.

Answer (score 1):

I have no ide if this will work but you can try.

```
jQuery("input[name=payment\\[method\\]]:radio").unbind('click');
```